# Makefile run command for each matching directory but exclude specific pattern

Tags: makefile

**QUESTION**

Using Make how do I run a command for every directory that contains a file matching *.csproj but does not including a file matching *.Test.csproj using pure make.

---

**SCENARIO**

I have previously used Fake and Rake extensively but this is my first time using Make to do anything over and above the simple use of dumb targets.

I have a simple makefile that compiles a .net core solution, runs some tests and then packages up a nuget package. Here is a simplified example.

```
build:
  dotnet build ./src \
    ...

test:
  dotnet test ./src/TestProject \
    ...

package:
  dotnet pack ./src/PackageProject \
    ...
```

I now want to introduce additional projects which are also packaged but I do not want to specify each project to package individually. I want the make file to automagically pick up each project that can be packaged. This method has been tried in tested in various Fake builds.

I have been able to implement the following matching on the projects `csproj` extension and works fine but I have not been able to filter out the test project which also gets packaged.

```
package: ./src/**/%.csproj

%.csproj:
  dotnet pack $(@D) \
    ...
```

I have been trying to understand the Make pattern rules and how to apply the `filter-out` function but have sadly failed. `$(filter-out src/**/*.Test.csproj, src/**/%.csproj)`

Would appreciate any help on figuring this one out.

**EDIT**

Based on the question from [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67439102/227200) if I run the following using `make package` using this dumbed down example:

```
package: ./src/*/%.csproj
    

%.csproj :
    echo $(@)
```

I get the following output:

```
echo src/Namespace.Project1/%.csproj
src/Namespace.Project1/%.csproj
echo src/Namespace.Project2/%.csproj
src/Namespace.Project2/%.csproj
echo src/Namespace.Test/%.csproj
src/Namespace.Test/%.csproj
```

Additionally based on MadScientist's comments I have also been able to create a list of the directories I want to call the dotnet pack command against but I am now stuck on how to call the target for each match.

*Note: I am trying to keep this pure Make and avoid using any bash specific syntax*

```
projects := $(filter-out $(dir $(wildcard ./src/Bombora.Namespace*Test/.) ), $(dir $(wildcard ./src/Namespace.*/.) ) )

package:
    echo $(projects)
```

Results in:

```
echo ./src/Namespace.Project1/ ./src/Namespace.Project2/
./src/Namespace.Project1/ ./src/Namespace.Project2/
```

**EDIT**

I have been able to make this work but I do not know if I have gone about it the correct way or if I am abusing something which will come back to bite me later.

This is what I am now doing which is working as expected:

```
PACKAGE_PROJECTS := $(filter-out $(wildcard ./src/Namespace*Test/*.csproj), $(wildcard ./src/Namespace*/*.csproj) ) 

package: $(PACKAGE_PROJECTS)
    
$(PACKAGE_PROJECTS): .
    dotnet pack $(@D) \
        ...
```

Comment: I really don't think you want to list `.` as a prerequisite of your projects.  I don't think that will do what you want.

Comment: I also strongly recommend you do not add extra whitespace into your variables; e.g. you don't use `...*.csproj) )` but instead remove spaces as `...*.csproj))`

Comment: @MadScientist - Thanks for the tip on the whitespace. The `.` is working it is matching on everything in the list which only contains the files matching *.csproj . At the end of the day I am only interested in the directories which is why I use `$(@D)` so feel free to suggest a better way. At the end of the day the question is about how do I run a command for every directory that contains a file matching `*.csproj` but not including `*.Test.csproj` using pure make. If we can answer that then the answer gets my vote.

Comment: @Bronumski  This can help you overcome ```ifneq ($(filter *.Test.csproj,$(PACKAGE_PROJECTS)),) ...$(PACKAGE_PROJECTS): .
    dotnet pack $(@D) \ ...endif```

Comment: No.  Prerequisites are NOT regular expressions, they're globbing expressions.  `.` is not a special character in a glob (that would be a disaster).  `.` is `.`: it means the current working directory, just like if you run `ls .` or `cd .` or whatever.  So you're saying that every project depends on the current working directory.  This doesn't make sense.  You don't need a prerequisite for every target.  You can just leave the prerequisite list empty.

Comment: If you'd have asked the question as clearly as you put it in your comment above in the first place it would have been a lot simpler to answer :)

Comment: Sometimes knowing the right question is the hardest part. I wanted to give the context because my terminology is based around other tools. Your questions to my question helped my rephrase my question.
"That, detective, is the right question." ;)
https://www.jlwranglerforums.com/forum/attachments/200-gif.26230/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make implements standard globbing as defined by POSIX.  It doesn't provide advanced globbing as implemented in some advanced shells like zsh (or bash if you enable it).

So, `**` is identical `*`; there's no globbing character that means "search in all subdirectories".  If you want to do that you need to use `find`.

Also, in make a pattern is a *template* that can match some target that you specifically want to build.  It's not a way to find targets.  And pattern rules only are pattern rules if the *target* contains the pattern character `%`; putting a `%` in a prerequisite of an explicit target doesn't do anything, make treats it as if it were just a `%` character.

so:

```
package: ./src/**/%.csproj
```

is identical to writing:

```
package: ./src/*/%.csproj
```

where it finds files matching the literal string `%.csproj` of which you probably don't have any.

I don't see how this `package` target does anything at all.

I don't understand what exactly you want to do: you need to make your question more explicit.  Make works on targets and prerequisites.  So, what is the target you want to build and what are the prerequisites used to create that target?  What is the make command line you are invoking, what is the output you got, and what is the intended output you want?

**ETA**

You asked:

> At the end of the day the question is about how do I run a command for every directory that contains a file matching *.csproj but not including *.Test.csproj using pure make.

This will get you that list:

```
TEST_PROJECTS := $(dir $(wildcard src/*/*.Test.csproj))
PROJECTS := $(filter-out $(TEST_PROJECTS),$(dir $(wildcard src/*/*.csproj)))

projects: $(PROJECTS)

$(PROJECTS):
        ...run commands...

.PHONY: $(PROJECTS)
```

You combine setting `PROJECTS` into one line if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the pattern matching, I can confirm that switching to `*` instead of `**` makes no difference. But calling the target package does do what I expect it to do but maybe for the wrong reason. If I call `make package` the dotnet pack command is run for each directory or the matched file passed in. I currently have three directories that contain a file with the mask `*.csproj`, this results in three calls to the dotnet pack command. The issue is that I want to filter one of them out.

Comment: Your edit works exactly as it should. I updated using your suggestion and removed the `.` prerequisite.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below changes which will help you understand applying a filter with make targets and getting ahead.
**Usage of filter and filter-out**:
**filter** : Select words in text that **match one** of the pattern words.
Syntax : $(filter pattern...,text)
**filter-out**: Select words in text that **do not match** any of the pattern words.
Syntax : $(filter-out pattern...,text)
In the below example I will use **filter** to match pattern and if the conditions evaluates to true , then 
 you can use your target with whatever execution you would like to do.

```
# List the project extensions that you would like to support
MYPROJECTS=.csproj .xyzproj

# MY_FILES would contain all files eg: abc.csproj  def.csproj  abc.xyzproj
# Below GETPATTERN will extract the suffix: eg. it would produce result .csproj .csproj .xyzproj
GETPATTERN:= $(suffix $(MY_FILES))

ifeq ($(filter $(GETPATTERN),$(MYPROJECTS)),)
package: 
    dotnet pack ./src/PackageProject
else
package: <default or any other dependency you want>
    dotnet pack ./src/PackageDefaultProject
endif
```